# Python Print format between statement and calculation

Tags: python

Sorry I'm trying to learn python but how I print this line so these (', are not printed?

Code:

```
y = 7
z = 7 - y
print('you need ', z, 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative')
```

Result:

```
('you need ', 6, 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative')
```

but I dont want the unnecessary parenthesizes, commas and weird spaces.

thanks

Comment: Seems like you're using Python-2.x. Try `print'you need ', z, 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative'` (remove surrounding parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python2 and the reason why the parentheses and commas get printed out is:
What you have after `print` is a tuple, namely this:

```
('you need ', z, 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative')
```

It's a tuple of three elements and python would print it out in the tuple form, therefore the parentheses and commas.
In Python 3, the parentheses won't get printed out as `print` is changed from a language construct(or to use their own word, "statement") to a function and requires parentheses on its arguments.

To change it to work on python2:

```
print 'you need ', z, 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative'
```

or

```
print ('you need ' + str(z) + 'more years of citizenship to become a US representative')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a `tuple` of the two strings and the number by surrounding it with the parentheses. Then, `print` takes the tuple and prints it using the special formatting that it always uses for tuples. `print` in python 2.7.x is a keyword, not a function, so you don't use parentheses with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print 'you need {0} more years of citizenship to ...'.format(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use string formatting:

```
print 'you need %d more years of citizenship to become a US representative' % z'
```

it will substitute %d (which indicates digit) with value of z

Answer (score 0):

In order to prepare for Python3, you can add to your script at the very top

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then use `print` as a function as you did in your question.